Where should I link people to justify the fact that we close opinionated and tool-seeking questions?
The FAQ article Question Close Reasons - Definitions and Guidance simply explains the standard set of reasons that questions are closed on Stack Overflow. But it doesn't seem to include a clear explanation of why we use these specific reasons.
I'm already aware of What is the point of closing questions for details and clarity, debugging details, needs more focus, or very low quality? which I recently worked on, to justify from the asker's perspective the fact that poorly asked questions should be closed in general; and I think it's self evident why the features in the title make a question "poorly asked". I also created Why should I help close "bad" questions that I think are valid, instead of helping the OP with an answer? to explain from the answerer's perspective why question closure is important in general.
But I think it's not self evident, simply from the descriptions, why "Primarily Opinion-Based" and "Seeking recommendations for software libraries, tutorials, tools, books, or other off-site resources" are in the standard set of close reasons. Simply referencing the goal of a Q&A site, or pointing at the tour, doesn't seem like a complete explanation either.
Where on Meta can I point users, to justify these closure reasons to them?

for POB, consider How can I encourage Stack Overflow to rein in the 'subjective' vigilantes? at MSE

Aside from the Help Center articles What types of questions should I avoid asking? and What topics can I ask about here? (since it's not our job to justify why rules exist when closing questions that violate them)...
For Tool Recommendations, you can point them here:

Why won't Stack Exchange reconsider the "recommend or find a tool" off-topic tag?

For Opinion-based questions, you can point them here:

Opinion based questions

Why cannot opinion-based questions be answered or implemented here?

Can we open up Stack Overflow to accept questions which are opinion-based? This induces a constructive answer of pros & cons & industry best practices


There are probably some good options on MSE as well.

I know some of these are included in SOCVR/auto-comments, should we add more of these there?
